# Is this wiki edit really incorrect?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/292417) to a tag wiki, and had three different responses.

One accept, one reject because "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." and one reject because "This edit does not follow any of our tag wiki guidelines and is unlikely to help instruct future visitors in the appropriate use of the tag."

To the first reject, I contend that the edit *is* correct and "an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post" doesn't really even apply in this case.

To the second reject, I'm not sure how I am violating any of the guidelines with this edit, and it does "help instruct future visitors" if they are having an issue while using a Starter Edition of some Office application.

Furthermore, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/292419), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/292415), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/292410) suggestion were all accepted with no rejections whatsoever and they are so similar I'd almost call them identical...

So, was I wrong in the three other cases?

Comment: I have since [resubmitted the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/292757), as I feel it is still appropriate and accurate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key difference between yours and the other three examples you provided is the amount of information. The three other examples are all much longer with more detail and reference links. The [word-vba](/questions/tagged/word-vba) tag has none of that. It's just a short little sentence and honestly, your edit doesn't really improve that wiki all that much. I'd disagree that it's "incorrect" but would agree that it's too minor and doesn't follow the tag wiki guidelines. Compared to the amount of text already present, the addition doesn't really contribute anything to the tag wiki.

You're basically adding a *side-note* to an already-extremely-short wiki. Adding it to the other wikis is more acceptable because it actually fits into the content around it and is relevant. The one that was rejected needs a major overhaul. It's like saying "you shouldn't eat the apple" without saying "the apple is rotten."

Comment: I do see your point about the overall wiki entry being too brief, and sure there would be some benefit to adding more, but I still see my edit as a valid and potentially helpful edit. If an edit is not wrong, then would its inclusion really hurt?

Comment: The apple is rotten! +1 for using an analogy without doing what I usually do: shoot myself in the foot. Figuratively. Well, maybe not with so much lasting effect. I guess it's really more like... See?? See what I mean? ;)